# Problem in getting result after invoking audio recorder and camera

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to capture 3 types of media: audio, video or picture and then write its path onto database. Following is the code:

```
switch(capture_type){
    case audiocapture:
        Intent intentA = new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
        startActivityForResult(intentA, ACTIVITY_RECORD_SOUND);
    break;

    case videocapture:
        Intent intentV = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intentV, ACTIVITY_RECORD_VIDEO);
        break;

    case piccapture:
        Intent intentP = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intentP, ACTIVITY_RECORD_PIC);
        break;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case ACTIVITY_RECORD_SOUND:
            if (resultCode==RESULT_CANCELED)
                Log.e("NewScreen.java","intent didn't return any result, or crashed during its operation..");

            try{ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put("audiouri", data.getDataString());
                values.put("videouri","NULL" );
                values.put("picuri", "NULL");
                myDB.insertOrThrow("Tag", null, values);
    }catch(Exception ex){
                Log.e("NewScreen.java", ex.toString());
            }
            break;

        case ACTIVITY_RECORD_VIDEO:
            if (resultCode==RESULT_CANCELED)
                Log.e("NewScreen.java","intent didn't return any result, or crashed during its operation..");

            try{ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("audiouri","NULL" );
                values.put("videouri",data.getDataString());
                values.put("picuri", "NULL");
                myDB.insertOrThrow("Tag", null, values);
                catch(SQLException e)
            }catch(Exception ex){
                Log.e("NewScreen.java", ex.toString());
            }
            break;

        case ACTIVITY_RECORD_PIC:
            if (resultCode==RESULT_CANCELED)
                Log.e("NewScreen.java","intent didn't return any result, or crashed during its operation..");

            try{ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put("audiouri", "NULL");
                values.put("videouri","NULL" );
                values.put("picuri", data.getDataString());
                try{Log.d("NewScreen.java","now going to insert values in table..");
                    myDB.insertOrThrow("Tag", null, values);
                }catch(SQLException e){Log.e("NewScreen.java", e.toString());}
                    Log.d("NewScreen.java","pic successfully inserted in table");
            }catch(Exception ex){
                    Log.e("NewScreen.java", ex.toString());
            }
            break;
    }
 }
```

Now there is an interesting case that all 3 behave differently. following are the outcomes:

1. ACTIVITY_RECORD_SOUND : resultCode is equal to 'RESULT_CANCELED'
2. ACTIVITY_RECORD_VIDEO : working perfectly
3. ACTIVITY_RECORD_PIC   : resultCode is **NOT** equal to 'RESULT_CANCELED' but **picuri=null**..

What is the problem with sound and image capture & how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

For pictures: try to set extra data with desired output file Uri in advance, just before startActivityForResult:

```
intentP.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, <your_Uri>);
```

Same problem here with sounds. The audio recorder application gets started but cancellation is received immediately after the startActivityForResult call. Reproduced on Asus Transformer, Honeycomb 3.2.
What test environment are you using? When do you receive the result?